# php array_map with static method of object

Tags: php, array-map

I want to use **array_map** with a static method but I fail.
Here is my code :

```
Class Buy {

    public function payAllBills() {
        $bill_list = OtherClass::getBillList();
        return array_map(array(self, 'pay'), $bill_list); // Issue line
    }

    private static function pay($bill) {
        // Some stuff
        return true;
    }

}
```

PHP gives me the error :

```
Use of undefined constant self - assumed 'self'
```

I have also tried :

```
return array_map('self::makeBean()', $model_list);
```

But it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea how to use array_map with static method ?

I have already read : [Can a method be used as a array_map function in PHP 5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077491/can-a-method-be-used-as-a-array-map-function-in-php-5-2) but this question is about standard methods, not statics.

Comment: Try this:- array_map(array(new Buy, 'pay'), $bill_list);

Comment: Thanks Ravi Hirani because your solution works too.

Comment: PHP5.2 Wow, worried that all these newer version (5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6) may have bugs iI suppose

Comment: Don't worry, I use 5.6, but I had found only this question about array_map and method :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php),

```
return array_map('self::pay', $model_list);
```

Note that your attempt included `()` in the method name string, which would be wrong

Comment: this syntax is [deprecated](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/partially-supported-callable-deprecation), use `array_map(self::pay(...), $someList)` or `array_map(self::class . '::pay', $someList)` instead.

Answer (score 12):

Let me extend @mark-baker's answer:

if you want to call a static method of another class, you have to put the full namespace into the quotes:

```
return array_map('Other\namespace\CustomClass::pay', $model_list);
```

Using the class per `use` is not enough:

```
// this is not enough:
// use Other\namespace\CustomClass;
return array_map('CustomClass::pay', $model_list); //does not work
```

Comment: If you were to use this  a class, this will clutter the code (multiple references on the same code). A solution to this is to make a private function and array_map over that.
`use Other\namespace\CustomClass;  class myClass {    private function pay($var) {        return CostomClass::pay($var);    }   public function payMe($model_list) { return array_map([$this, 'pay'], $model_list);} } `

Answer (score 10):

According to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

> Static class methods can also be passed without instantiating an object of that class by passing the class name instead of an object at index 0.

There are [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2594111/4511958) for a class to reference it's own name, depending on the situation. One clean, efficient way in PHP 5.5+ is `self::class` ([class keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)). (Note: It's also a particularly good method to use if you're using a code editor with intellisense, because the editor can then properly identify the class reference for doing things like renaming and go-to-references.)

So, you can do the following:

```
array_map([self::class, 'pay'], $bill_list);
```

This also works when you're referring to a static method on some other namespaced class, like so:

```
use Some\Cool\OtherClass;

array_map([OtherClass::class, 'pay'], $bill_list);
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this works but for those like me (without enough coffe) do note that `OtherClass::class` is **not a string**, it's called directly. So pay attention to call it *without* quotes.

Comment: I was gonna comment that calling a method by name in a string could confuse the IDE code completion but to my surprise this is recognized! At least PhpStorm (2023.2) recognizes the references both ways. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.6 - 7.3:

```
array_map('self::pay'], $bill_list); # works
array_map(['self', 'pay'], $bill_list); # works

array_map('\\Some\\Name\\Space\\SomeClass::method',$array); # works
array_map(['\\Some\\Name\\Space\\SomeClass','method'],$array); # works

use \Some\Name\Space\SomeClass;  # alias to local namespace fails:
array_map('SomeClass::method',$array); # fails
array_map(['SomeClass','method'],$array); # fails
```

The error given is:

> PHP Warning:  array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'SomeClass' not found

```
use SomeLongClassName as Foo; # alias within namespace fails:
array_map("Foo::method",$array); # fails
array_map(['Foo','method'],$array); # fails
```

The error given is:

> PHP Warning:  array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'Foo' not found

One workaround to shorten the line length and/or re-use it:

```
const SomeClass = '\\Some\\Name\\Space\\SomeClass';
array_map([SomeClass,'method'],$array); # works
```

or if you use the foreign static method many times over in a class:

```
class MyClass{
    # in PHP 7.1+ you can make this private:
    const SCMethod = '\\Some\\Name\\Space\\SomeClass::method';

    public function myMethod($array){
        return array_map(self::SCMethod, $array); # works
    }
}
```